# Need a regular expression for a spreadsheet calculator

Tags: java, regex

I'm building a calculator which can operate on cells in a spreadsheet, and need a regular expression for part of it.

What I need to parse out are the following:

- digits: integers.
- cell names: are named like 'alpha character' + 'digit' ie. A1, B2...
- operations:  +, -, *, /

An example would be something like:

```
23 A4 * 2 B5 /
```

Here I would want the groups to be: 23, A4, *, 2, B5, /

It shouldn't be tough, but the operations throw me off.

The reason for wanting a regex and not just splitting on spaces is for validation.  I'm looking for some very specific things, so I thought a regex would be the best thing to use.

Comment: Why do you think a regexp would be of use in here?

Comment: The operations throw you off because they create a [non-regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), which by definition cannot be parsed with a regular one.

Comment: Have you heard of Antlr? It's a great project. And I think it will help you.

Comment: @Cameron: Would they? He did not require parenthesis.

Comment: @Bergi I want to use a regex instead of just splitting on spaces to validate the input.  If there's another way I should do it, let me know

Comment: For parsing it'would better to use a ``stack`` rather using ``RegEx`` for this purpose.

Comment: I'm thinking that a regex isn't the answer.  From some research, it looks like what I'm trying to do isn't supported in most languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some research, and the comments above, it looks like a regex probably isn't the best way to do what I wanted.

I'll have to try splitting, then looping over all the split groups to validate.

Answer (score 0):

> Here I would want the groups to be: 23, A4, *, 2, B5, /

```
String[] groups = "23 A4 * 2 B5 / ".split(" ");
```

Comment: @infgeoax  What about it?  Your input seems to be 'not the question'.  Ask your own question if you want to pursue parsing the alternate string.

Comment: Just saying the input might not be well formed (space separated), but also valid.

Comment: @infgeoax  I interpret 'valid' for this question to be 'space delimited values'.  If my interpretation of validity is too narrow, the OP can clarify.